# Django - filter queryset disregarding spaces

Tags: regex, django, forms, validation

I have a model that contains phone numbers `external_number`, stored as a char field:

***models.py***

```
class PhoneRecord(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Call to %s (%s)" % (self.external_number, self.call_date.strftime("%c"))

    INBOUND = "I"
    OUTBOUND = "O"
    DIRECTION_CHOICES = (
        (INBOUND, "Inbound"),
        (OUTBOUND, "Outbound"),
    )
    external_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    call_date = models.DateTimeField()
    external_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    call_duration = models.TimeField()
    call_direction = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=DIRECTION_CHOICES, default=INBOUND)
    call = models.FileField(upload_to='calls/%Y/%m/%d')
```

The form is cleaning and storing the data using the `UKPhoneNumberField` from https://github.com/g1smd/django-localflavor-UK-forms/blob/master/django/localflavor/uk/forms.py

This means that the number is stored in the database in the format 01234 567890 i.e. with a space in.

I have created a filter using [django-filters](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) which works well, when searching for partial phone number *except* that it doesn't filter correctly when the search term doesn't include the space. i.e.

- search for `01234` returns the record for the example above
- search for `567890` returns the record for the  example above
- search for `01234 567890` returns the record for the example above
- search for `01234567890` **does not** return the record for the example above

Now, I could subject the form on the filter to the same restrictions (i.e. `UKPhoneNumberField` as the input screen, but that then takes away the ability to search for partial phone numbers.

I have also explored the possibility of using something like [django-phonenumber-field](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field) that will control both the model and the form, but the validation provided by `UKPhoneNumberField` allows me to validate based on the type of number entered (e.g. mobile or geographical).

What I would ideally like is either

1. My filter to ignore spaces that are either input by the user in their search query, or any spaces that are in the stored value. Is this even possible?
2. Apply the validation provided by `UKPhoneNumberField` to another field type without having to analyse and re-write all the regular expressions provided.
3. Some other UK Phone number validation I have not found yet!

Comment: I know this does not answer your question but if I were you I would store the numbers without spaces, and display them formatted when necessary.

Comment: Thanks @Selcuk - I may have to go down this route. I've been picking through the code for `UKPhoneNumberField` I might be able to do this quicker than another solution!

Answer (score 0):

You could setup the filter to do something like this:

```
phone_number = "01234 567890"
parts = phone_number.split(" ")
PhoneRecord.objects.filter(
    external_number__startswith="{} ".format(parts[0]),
    external_number__endswith=" {}".format(parts[1]),
)
```

That way the filter is looking for the first half of the number with the space and then the second half of the number with the space as well. The only records that would be returned would be ones that had the value of "01234 567890"

Comment: Thanks for this @schillingt, but it's worth noting 2 things: that I would like the user to be able to search regardless of the location of the space: I want them (for this example) to be able to search `3456` and it  return this example record. Also, if they search without spaces (`01234567890`) I don't think this would find the record?

Comment: No this would not work for the search term ```3456```. If that's an absolute requirement, then you should store them without spaces like Selcuk suggested. It'll make your life a hell of a lot easier and you can always format the number when it's being displayed.  For the search without a space, you'd need to normalize that search value so it would include the space.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a custom filter with a `field_class = UKPhoneFilter`. This means I can't search on partial numbers, but that was removed as a requirement from the project.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about normalizing the data before you save them into your DB.
You could just use [django-phonenumber-field](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field) which does just that.

In regarding your problem you can always use django's `regex` field postfix to query over regular expression.

e.g. `MyModel.objects.filter(myfiel__regex=r'[a-Z]+')`