# Django: How to strip out spaces in the model field value and filter?

Tags: python, django

name = "New York", "New Jersey", "New America" etc

By using the following query I will get all the results with the string contains **New**

```
City.objects.filter(name__icontains="New") # Perfect
```

But How to find  New York with out adding the space between new york

```
City.objects.filter(name__icontains="NewYork") # Not getting New York
```

How to filter ? Please let me know your views

Answer (score 3):

No need to strip anything, regex would do the job

```
City.objects.filter(name__regex=r'(?i)new[\s\w]+')
```

`(?i)` makes the expression case insensitive, although you could also simply use `__iregex`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex

Comment: thanks..if you have time, could you write your  style of regex for stripping the spaces between the values..in the mean time, I will try myself

Comment: Thats true.we could you iregex for case insenstive. But your regex doesnt work for any value

Answer (score 1):

you already got an excellent answer, but here is another way you might want to try out:

```
City.objects.filter(name__icontains=''.join(s.split())
```

assuming `s` is the string you filter by (e.g. "New York").

See [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) for further info

Comment: however, reading your question again, I have the impression you may be trying to match records with 'New York' against 'NewYork'. In that case, Django's ORM would have to be able to perform such a match, stripping/ignoring the whitespace in the field and comparing it to the key string. That would be an interesting question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767427/django-filter-queryset-disregarding-spaces for some interesting info on the subject