# Django filter without spacing

Tags: python, django

if i have two records in database like something 00 and something00. I want to get both of them if i write down something 00 or something00. I tried:

```
Item.objects.filter(name__icontains="something 00")
```

but it doesn't work and i only get one result. Any other solutions?

Comment: try `Item.objects.filter(name__icontains="'something','00")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: How to strip out spaces in the model field value and filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224415/django-how-to-strip-out-spaces-in-the-model-field-value-and-filter)

Comment: in this situation it will be good, but if i'll have something 00 xx and e.t.c it will become more complicated

Comment: @rlfrahm I tried this one but doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Taking the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30224493/2824391 and modifying to your case...

What you need to do is trim any whitespace in your search query, then use the regex from that answer, like so:

```
search_term = 'something 00'
Item.objects.filter(name__iregex=r'%s[\s\w]+' % search_term.replace(' ',''))
```

This should match anything like `something00` and `something 00`.

Fyi, here's a good website I use to check my regex (I am in no way affiliated with them): http://regexr.com/

Comment: It still doesn't work. this is my filter
Q(name__iregex=r'%s[\s\w]+' % item_name.replace(' ',''))|Q(name__icontains=item_name)|Q(seller__name__icontains=item_name)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list_of_string = ['something', '00']
Item.objects.filter(name__icontains=list_of_string)
```

**Edit**

```
Item.objects.filter(name__iregex=r'(?i)Something[\s\w]+')
```

Comment: If i have in database like something00 and i write in search input something 00 it displays nothing. so this solution doesn't work

Comment: Wow. very clever solution. Like the declaring variable part. Maybe he could do:  `abc =  ['something', '00'] 
list_of_string = abc
Item.objects.filter(name__icontains=list_of_string)`